# react quill with react hook form & nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, react-quill

I'm implementing editor using react-quill, react-hook-form in nextjs.

```
const QuillNoSSRWrapper = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
});

const Editor = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, setValue } = useForm<Content>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (document) {
      register('content', { required: true });
    }
  }, [register]);

  const onValid = (data: Content) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  const editorChange = (editorState: string) => {
    setValue('content', editorState);
  };

  const editorContent = watch('content');
  return (
    <div onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
      <QuillNoSSRWrapper
        value={editorContent}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        onChange={editorChange}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

I tried to add `if(document)...` but same error.

So, I changed `form` to `div`

like this

```
    <form>
      <QuillNoSSRWrapper
        value={editorContent}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        onChange={editorChange}
      />
      <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(onValid)} />
    </form>
```

The `data` ​​I entered are shown in the console, but when I **refresh** I get the same error again.

Is there no way to use the **form** tag without using a **div**? I am trying to implement with react hook form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Hydration error that I had in NextJS v13 using the following trick to only render the form during the client rendering and not during the SSR:

```
export function LoginForm() {
  const [initialRenderComplete, setInitialRenderComplete] = useState(false)

  // This useEffect will only run once, during the first client render
  useEffect(() => {
    // Updating a state causes a re-render
    setInitialRenderComplete(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      /* more html here if necessary ... */

      {initialRenderComplete && (
        <form>
          <input .... />
          <submit .... />
        </form>
      )}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Take a look at this article that explains very well the issue: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/